# How to use memcpy in Struct in c?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, memcpy

I have a struct:

```
struct points{
int i;
int x;
int y;
};
```

I made an array of the struct and named it temp. Then I made another and named it pt. Suppose I put some contents to temp. How can I copy the elements of temp to pt?

Here's my code of memcpy and the compiler says it's segmentation fault. Help please.

```
#define MAX_POINTS 400
struct points temp[MAX_POINTS];
/* Some code to input elements to array temp */
struct points pt[i]; /* array of struct with i elements*/
memcpy(&pt, &temp, sizeof (temp));
```

Comment: `pt` and `temp` are already pointers when you don't use the array dereference.  Remove the `&` in your memcpy.  Segfault is probably because the address-of first element of pt or temp (cast as an integer) is outside your heap range.

Comment: When I tried to print the contents of pt.i, it printed correctly:
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
But again, how do you get rid of the seg fault?

Comment: @PaulProgrammer Still, the seg fault is there. Should I use malloc? And how would I use it?

Comment: what's your definition of i?

Answer (score 3):

You have to be careful to only copy the size of the smaller of the two, here I suppose that `i < MAX_POINTS`

```
memcpy(pt, temp, sizeof pt);
```

Also as others already said the `&` are not correct. You need a pointer to the first element, that is `&pt[0]` for example, or just `pt` as the array decays to `&pt[0]` in that context.

Note that your allocation of `pt` is a variable length array if `i` is a variable. This can be dangerous and lead to a stack overflow if `i` is getting too large. So if you plan to use large arrays here, better use `malloc`:

```
struct points* pt = malloc(sizeof(struct points[i]));
memcpy(pt, temp, sizeof(struct points[i]);
```

Unfortunately then, you can't use `sizeof pt` for the `memcpy`.